# как удалить со строки символ \ PHP?

Tags: php

Необходимо убрать символ с текста (longtext) символ 
пробую так (вручную строку такую же задать):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все получается.

но если приходят данные (longtext):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
которые я обрабатываю потом как XML, то символ не убирается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что в строке на самом деле нет никакого символа \ — вы явно смотрите строковый литерал, в котором `\r` является специальным синтаксисом и обозначает символ возврата каретки (а `\n` это символ переноса строки). Если вы хотите их удалить, то делайте что-то вроде `str_replace('\r', '', ...)`

Comment: @andreymal не там около \x1A нужно убрать

Comment: Ну там то же самое, `\x1A` это один спецсимвол и убирать надо конкретно его `str_replace('\x1a', '', ...)`

Comment: И убирать-то их зачем?

Comment: функция simplexml_load_string выдает ошибку из-за него.

Comment: И как ошибка эта выглядит?

Comment: str_replace('\x1a', '', ...) так тоже пробовал))

Comment: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 129: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 26

Comment: `\x1A` это управляющий символ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character может означать потерянный символ, недействительный или ошибочный, или конц файла https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B проверь данные, на его месте должно что-то быть?

Comment: @Jean-Claude не точно не конец файла, это Юр лицо + скорее всего номер транзакции. ну убрать его нужно или может есть другой способ, может как-то эту ошибку отключить

Comment: в mySql выглядит так
<title>EKASA APUESTAS ON L(тут стрелка)AMUDIOES2011052156</title>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться

```
$var = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $input);
```

Или

```
$var = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $input);
```

И проверьте, что в итоге используете переменную $var в simplexml_load_string, а не $input.

Comment: Добрый человек, дай БОГ тебе здоровья. Крепко жму руку!!!